# How can I create a logging function in firebase for auth.user().onCreate() trigger?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to log each time an account is created and deleted.

I created a trigger `functions.auth.user().onCreate()` and as I understand it returns an `user` object as in the docs: [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/v8/firebase.User), [and here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/auth-events).

The functions deploy without trouble but when the trigger is called it throws an error:

```
Error: Process exited with code 16
at process.<anonymous> (/layers/google.nodejs.functions-framework/functions-framework/node_modules/@google-cloud/functions-framework/build/src/invoker.js:92:22)
at process.emit (events.js:314:20)
at process.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:483:12)
at process.exit (internal/process/per_thread.js:168:15)
at sendCrashResponse (/layers/google.nodejs.functions-framework/functions-framework/node_modules/@google-cloud/functions-framework/build/src/logger.js:44:9)
at process.<anonymous> (/layers/google.nodejs.functions-framework/functions-framework/node_modules/@google-cloud/functions-framework/build/src/invoker.js:88:44)
at process.emit (events.js:314:20)
at process.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:483:12)
at processPromiseRejections (internal/process/promises.js:209:33)
at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:98:32)
```

Error which I cannot understand.

Here is my code

```
// functions/index.js    
const functions = require('firebase-functions')
const admin = require('firebase-admin')
const { google } = require('googleapis')
const { firestore } = require("firebase-admin");

exports.logging = require('./logging');

admin.initializeApp()
// And other working functions
```

The actual functions

```
    // functions/logging.js

const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
const { firestore } = require('firebase-admin');

const authUserTrigger = functions.auth.user()

exports.userSignup = authUserTrigger.onCreate((user) => {
  storeUser(user)
})

exports.userDelete = authUserTrigger.onDelete((user) => {
  storeUser(user)
})

    async function storeUser(user) {
      // functions.logger.log(user.email) -> this works

      // Destructured original object
      let updatedUser = (({ displayName, email }) => ({ displayName, email }))(user);
      functions.logger.log('updatedUser', updatedUser )
      await admin
        .firestore()
        .collection('logs')
        .doc('users')
        .collection('signup')
        .set({
          user: {updatedUser}, // I think this is the culprint
          // user,  This doesn't work either
          createTimestamp: firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp()
        }, { merge: true })
    
    };
```

Thank you in advance

EDIT ==========
@Tanay was right. Needed to change `set` to `add`.

Comment: You cannot set a collection in firebase, it must be a document. If you want to add a document to the collection with an auto id, you can use add on the collection with the data

Comment: Thanks. But I have other working functions with that pattern. async function updateRegisteredUserCount(delta) {
  await admin
    .firestore()
    .collection('counters')
    .doc('registeredUsers')
    .set({ count: firestore.FieldValue.increment(delta), updateTimestamp: firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp() }, { merge: true });
}

Comment: You are indeed using `set()` on a `DocumentReference` in those _other_ functions but not in the one in your question. Have you tried using `add` as suggested by @Tanay?

Comment: We need more debugging information.  What happens if you remove the call to Firestore that you think is the culprit? What do the logs say for the entire invocation (not just the error stack trace)?

Comment: @Tanay you were right thanks.

Comment: Hi @MarcoSantana ,  could you please post it as an answer so that it could also help the community.

Answer (score 1):

As @Tanay stated, you cannot use `set()` in a collection in Firebase, it must be a document. If you want to add a document to the collection with an auto ID then you can use `add()` on the collection with the data.